# client server authentication by sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets

I want to perform authentication between client server but it always returns authentication error even if the login and password are correct if someone has an idea how I can solve this problem, it shows me:
run:
enter login
Java
enter password
Java
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

---

active server on port 8889
login = javajava, and password = null
authentication error

If you have a suggestion how authentication can be achieved regardless of the password and login.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Kindle {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   String host="127.0.0.1";
         int port =8889;

       try (Socket socket = new Socket(host,port)) {
           OutputStream flux=socket.getOutputStream();
           OutputStreamWriter sortie=new OutputStreamWriter(flux);
           System.out.println("enter login");
           String login =sc.nextLine();

           sortie.write(login);
           sortie.flush();

           System.out.println("enter password");
           String  password =sc.nextLine();

           sortie.write(password);
           sortie.flush();
       }

  }    
}

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
 public class Bibliotheque {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port=8889;
        Bib_Kindle b=new Bib_Kindle();
        ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(port); 
        System.out.println("serveur active sur port "+port);
        while(true){
            try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
                InputStream flux=socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader entree=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (flux));
                String login =entree.readLine();
                String password =entree.readLine();
                System.out.println("login  = "+login +",and password = "+password);

                if(login.equals(b.getLogin()) &&password.equals(b.getPassword())){
                    System.out.println("Welcome, " + login);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("erreur authentification");        }
            }

        }
        }


}



public class Bib_Kindle {
  private String login="java";
       private   String password="java";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    public Bib_Kindle() {

    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, socket will write data onto server's input steam in the same line and `readline` will read the whole data at once hence, second deadline will have nothing to read.

Solution:
You need to explicitly mention the line break while writing your input from socket using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` so use

```
sortie.write(login + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

can make a separate static method to write and append `System.getProperty("line.separator")` property.

Comment: Thank you for your response the console shows me
login = javajava, and password = java
authentication error

Comment: make sure you to remove `sortie.write(login);` and use the `sortie.write(login + System.getProperty("line.separator"));` as it will write the login value (java) and the separator in single write.

Comment: Please ,do you have any idea how i can register by login and password before doing an authentication.

Comment: @Adam for that, you need database on server side sql with jdbc to store info for signup and then login validation.